# Why does this query run faster? (UNIQUE vs NOT EXISTS)

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I am trying to run a simple operation where I have a table called insert_base and another table called insert_values (both with attributes a,b), and I want to just copy all the values in insert_values into insert_base whilst **avoiding duplicates** - that is, I do not want to insert a tuple already in insert_values, and also do not want to insert the same tuple twice into insert_values. I am currently looking at two query methods to do this:

```
INSERT INTO insert_base SELECT DISTINCT * FROM insert_values IV
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM insert_base IB WHERE IV.a = IB.a AND IV.b = IB.b);
```

and another that involves using a UNIQUE constraint on insert_base(a,b):

```
INSERT INTO insert_base SELECT * FROM insert_values ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

However, every time I run this the first query runs significantly faster (500ms compared to 1sec + 300msec), and I am not sure why that is the case? Do the 2 queries not do roughly the same thing? I am aware that the UNIQUE constraint just puts an index on (a,b), but would that not make it faster than the first method? In fact, when I run the first method with an index on (a,b), it actually runs *slightly slower* than without any index (or unique constraint), which confuses me even more.

Any help would be much appreciated. I am running all this in postgresql by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query does more work than the first. It attempts to insert every row from your `insert_values` table, then when it sometimes hits a conflict it abandons the insert.

Your first query's WHERE clause filters out the rows that can't be inserted before attempting to insert them.

Comment: Thank you, so is it the case that in the second query, for each tuple being inserted, it checks every tuple in insert_base with the tuple being inserted using the index on insert_values, and rejects the tuple if it is inside insert_base - OR is it the case that it first inserts the tuple, and then checks if the unique constraint is upheld?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the first choice you mentioned.